# WPF Binding into grandson

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="grandson.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:grandson"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Root x:Key="RootControl"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ContentControl.Content.ContentControl.DataContext.Text}"/>

        <ContentControl Name="ContentControl" Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource RootControl}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Root.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="grandson.Root"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:grandson"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="Red">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:Children x:Key="Children"/>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:RootViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl Name="ContenControl" Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource Children}"/>
        <Label Content="Root" FontSize="72" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Children.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="grandson.Children"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:grandson"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Background="Yellow">
    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <local:ChildrenViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="Children" FontSize="72" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" />
        <Label Grid.Row="1" FontSize="72" Content="{Binding Text}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ChildrenViewModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace grandson
{
    public class ChildrenViewModel
    {
        public ChildrenViewModel()
        {

        }
        public string Text { get { return "asdf"; } }
    }
}
```

Qustion is how can I bind to a Children.DataContext.Text from the MainWindow?

```
**Text="{Binding ContentControl.Content.ContentControl.DataContext.Text}"**
```

It is working for Root control DataContext

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ContentControl,Path=Content.DataContext.Property}"/>
```

How do I get access to ContentControl.Content from the MainWindow.ContentControl as Root UserControl?

Answer (score 0):

Resoloved by added property Children

```
namespace grandson
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Root.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Root : UserControl
    {
        public Root()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Control Children
        {
            get { return this.ContentControl; }
        }
    }
}
```

And binding that way:

```
<Window x:Class="grandson.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:grandson"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:Root x:Key="RootControl"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content.Children.Content.DataContext.Text, 
            ElementName=ContentControl}"/>

        <ContentControl Name="ContentControl" Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource RootControl}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```